# ViewPager fragment content is blank for first time in Android

Tags: android-fragments

In my application, I use `ViewPager`. In `ViewPager`fragment I use a third fragment, but the first fragment content is blank for first time,when i come back from third fragment the first fragment contents are coming..
I have searched a lot of information but nothing is clear. Can somebody give a clear solution and an example, please?

My code:

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //int limit = (adapter.getCount() > 1 ? adapter.getCount() - 1 : 1);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
       // viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(limit);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setTabTextColors(Color.parseColor("#313B6f"), Color.parseColor("#313B6f"));
       // viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
    }




    private void setupViewPager(final ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new Selling(), "Selling");
       adapter.addFrag(new Buying(), "Buying");
        adapter.addFrag(new Watching(), "Watching");
        //viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        /*viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            Boolean first = true;
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (first && positionOffset == 0 && positionOffsetPixels == 0){
                    onPageSelected(0);
                    first = false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                System.out.println("pageee" + position);
               }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });*/
    }


    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();



        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            System.out.println("pageeeitem" + position);

            return mFragmentList.get(position);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
             return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);

        }


    }
```

Comment: your view pager inside fragment or activity?

Comment: viewpager in activity

Comment: Can somebody give a clear solution and an example, please ?

Comment: Can somebody give a solution?

Comment: can u pls use Pager adapter insead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter?

Comment: Take a look at your `Selling Fragment`. Is there something that would keep it from being rendered at first? When you page to the third fragment then back to the first, the first fragment is recreated. What happens if you scroll to the second fragment then back to the first? Does it appear or is it still blank?

Comment: No its not appear..its appear only when move from third fragment

Comment: I used pager adapter also..but same issue is there

Comment: Post your `Selling Fragment`. Also, I just happened to see your comments by accident. You need to use tags to communicate to commenters on your questions like this @AbserveTech. How this works is found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125208/when-exactly-do-i-get-comment-notifications).